# Parsing error: Identifier 'React' has already been declared. (9:7)

Tags: reactjs

I am using React 17, That,s I did not use import React from "react" in both but this error is coming again and again

```
app.js

`import Restaurant from './component/Basics/restaurant'

const App = () => {
   return (
     <div>
    <Restaurant />
     </div>
        )
 }

 export default App;
```

2nd page

```
const Restaurant = () => {
 return (
   <div>Hello from restaurant</div>
     )
 }
 export default Restaurant
```

Comment: hi could you please tell some more information because it's not enough information

Comment: I just deleted the file from where I was getting the error. Maybe it was from a previous file that I did create and deleted for a reason.